# Unable to generate an X.509 certificate with a custom crypto.Signer implementation

Tags: go, cryptography

I am trying to generate an X.509 certificate based on an RSA key pair stored in an HSM. I use [this PKCS #11 implementation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/miekg/pkcs11) to communicate with my HSM.

Since my cryptographic objects are stored in the latter, if the operations I want to perform need the private key (a signature for example), I have to implement [the crypto.Signer interface](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto#Signer) to be able to "access the private key". Here is this implementation.

```golang
type RSASigner struct {
    PrivateKey p11.PrivateKey
    PublicKey  *rsa.PublicKey
}

func (s RSASigner) Public() crypto.PublicKey {
    return s.PublicKey
}

func (s RSASigner) Sign(_ io.Reader, digest []byte, _ crypto.SignerOpts) ([]byte, error) {
    return s.PrivateKey.Sign(pkcs11.Mechanism{Mechanism: pkcs11.CKM_SHA512_RSA_PKCS}, digest)
}

func NewRSASigner(privateKey p11.PrivateKey) (*RSASigner, error) {
    var (
        modulus, publicExponent []byte
        err                     error
    )

    // Retrieve modulus n from the private key
    // Reminder: n = p * q
    modulus, err = p11.Object(privateKey).Attribute(pkcs11.CKA_MODULUS)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Retrieve public exponent (e: "always" 65537) from the private key
    // Reminder: φ(n) = (p - 1) * (q - 1), e such that 1 < e < φ(n) and e and φ(n) are co prime
    publicExponent, err = p11.Object(privateKey).Attribute(pkcs11.CKA_PUBLIC_EXPONENT)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Public key is (e, n)
    publicKey := &rsa.PublicKey{
        N: new(big.Int).SetBytes(modulus),
        E: int(big.NewInt(0).SetBytes(publicExponent).Uint64()),
    }

    return &RSASigner{PrivateKey: privateKey, PublicKey: publicKey}, nil
}
```

This implementation works. For example, to create a CSR, [the CreateCertificateRequest function](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/x509#CreateCertificateRequest) requires the private key to sign the CSR (`priv any` parameter), which is where I provide an instance of `RSASigner`.

[The CreateCertificate function](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/x509#CreateCertificate) is somewhat similar, the parameter `pub` is the public key of the certificate to be generated and `priv` is the private key of the signer.

In the code below, I am trying to generate a self-signed X.509 certificate, so according to the API, the `template` and `parent` parameters are the same.

```golang
func (t *Token) X509(id, objectType, output string) ([]time.Duration, error) {
    startFunction := time.Now()

    var (
        keyType            int
        privateKeyTemplate []*pkcs11.Attribute
        privateKeyObject   p11.Object
        err                error
        timings            []time.Duration
        signer             *RSASigner
        cert               []byte
        file               *os.File
        writtenBytes       int
    )

    objectType = strings.ToLower(objectType)

    if objectType != "rsa" && objectType != "ec" {
        logger.Fatalf("%s: unrecognized type, it can only be equal to rsa or ec", objectType)
    }

    switch objectType {
    case "rsa":
        keyType = pkcs11.CKK_RSA
    case "ec":
        keyType = pkcs11.CKK_EC
    }

    // Creation of the template to find the private key based on the given id (PKCS #11 attribute CKA_ID)
    privateKeyTemplate = []*pkcs11.Attribute{
        pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_KEY_TYPE, keyType),
        pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_CLASS, pkcs11.CKO_PRIVATE_KEY),
        pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_ID, id),
    }

    startFindObject := time.Now()
    privateKeyObject, err = t.session.FindObject(privateKeyTemplate)
    timings = append(timings, time.Since(startFindObject))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Creation of the X.509 certificate template
    certTemplate := &x509.Certificate{
        SerialNumber: big.NewInt(2023),
        Subject: pkix.Name{
            CommonName: "test",
        },
        SignatureAlgorithm: x509.SHA512WithRSA,
        NotBefore:          time.Now(),
        NotAfter:           time.Now().AddDate(1, 0, 0),
    }

    // Instantiate the RSASigner with the found private key object
    signer, err = NewRSASigner(p11.PrivateKey(privateKeyObject))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    startCreateCert := time.Now()
    cert, err = x509.CreateCertificate(rand.Reader, certTemplate, certTemplate, signer.PublicKey, signer)
    timings = append(timings, time.Since(startCreateCert))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    file, err = os.Create(output)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    writtenBytes, err = file.Write(cert)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    logger.Printf("Wrote %d bytes in %s", writtenBytes, output)

    return append(timings, time.Since(startFunction)), nil
}
```

This function returns the following error regardless of the key type (RSA or EC).

```
FATA[2022-12-22 10:48:50] x509: signature over certificate returned by signer is invalid: crypto/rsa: verification error
```

This error is returned if the `crypto.Signer` implementation [was not done correctly](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.4:src/crypto/x509/x509.go;l=1600).

I implemented `crypto.Signer` to try to do the same thing with a key pair on elliptic curve but the error is the same.

I also tried different hash algorithms in the `Sign` function but it doesn't change anything.

The error seems to come from the implementation of `crypto.Signer` although it works for generating a CSR.

Comment: Where does this error exactly happen? I don't see any verification function and "verification error" is very broad. I'm not fully trusting the error message, it could be any verification error e.g. key lookup. Your certificate template is very incomplete; you don't indicate matching subject & issuer for instance which would be required for any self signed cert.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, this error is raised by the [CreateCertificate](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.4:src/crypto/x509/x509.go;l=1599-1601) function when I check if the error is different from `nil`. The addition of the information you mention (issuer, subject...) is done by the `CreateCertificate` function itself: retrieve the issuer, the subject and [initialization of these fields](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.4:src/crypto/x509/x509.go;l=1550-1559;bpv=0;bpt=1). Of course, the certificate template is light but it should be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I've had the solution to this problem for several months now, I've never taken the time to share the answer but, the time has come.

When we sign things via PKCS #11 directly, we need to manage hash prefixes by manually prefixing the hash with the **DigestInfo** value referenced here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#page-43.

To be more precise, for **RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5** signatures, the input to the actual signature function is an ASN.1 DER-encoded structure. PKCS #11 has hash-specific mechanisms (e.g. **CKM_SHA256_RSA_PKCS**) which know how to generate that structure, but they all assume the data is un-hashed, which is not the case with the **crypto.Signer** interface, so we have to use the generic **CKA_RSA_PKCS** mechanism, which just performs the raw signature operation. This means we have to generate the ASN.1 structure ourselves, which we can do by just having the correct prefixes for all the hashes we might want to use.

Thanks to the **opts** parameter of type **crypto.SignerOpts**, we can retrieve the identifier of the hash function of type **crypto.Hash** when the **Sign()** function is called, and apply the correct prefix.

```golang
type Signer struct {
    priKey p11.PrivateKey
    pubKey *rsa.PublicKey
}

var hashPrefixes = map[crypto.Hash][]byte{
    crypto.SHA256: {0x30, 0x31, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x60, 0x86, 0x48, 0x01, 0x65, 0x03, 0x04, 0x02, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x04, 0x20},
    crypto.SHA384: {0x30, 0x41, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x60, 0x86, 0x48, 0x01, 0x65, 0x03, 0x04, 0x02, 0x02, 0x05, 0x00, 0x04, 0x30},
    crypto.SHA512: {0x30, 0x51, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x60, 0x86, 0x48, 0x01, 0x65, 0x03, 0x04, 0x02, 0x03, 0x05, 0x00, 0x04, 0x40},
}

func (s Signer) Public() crypto.PublicKey {
    return s.pubKey
}

func (s Signer) Sign(_ io.Reader, digest []byte, opts crypto.SignerOpts) ([]byte, error) {
    return s.priKey.Sign(*pkcs11.NewMechanism(pkcs11.CKM_RSA_PKCS, nil), append(hashPrefixes[opts.HashFunc()], digest...))
}

func NewSigner(key p11.PrivateKey) (*Signer, error) {
    // Retrieve modulus n from the private key
    // Reminder: n = p * q
    modulus, err := p11.Object(key).Attribute(pkcs11.CKA_MODULUS)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var pubExp []byte
    // Retrieve public exponent (e: "always" 65537) from the private key
    // Reminder: φ(n) = (p - 1) * (q - 1), e such that 1 < e < φ(n) and e and φ(n) are co prime
    pubExp, err = p11.Object(key).Attribute(pkcs11.CKA_PUBLIC_EXPONENT)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Public key is (e, n)
    pubKey := &rsa.PublicKey{
        N: new(big.Int).SetBytes(modulus),
        E: int(new(big.Int).SetBytes(pubExp).Uint64()),
    }

    return &Signer{priKey: key, pubKey: pubKey}, nil
}
```

It works like a charm. However, there is something better to do.

The **CKM_RSA_PKCS** mechanism provides a signature of the **RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5** type. I leave it to interested readers to do their own research on this old signature scheme, which should no longer be used in new products/software.

Indeed, it is recommended to use the **CKM_RSA_PKCS_PSS** mechanism, which provides a signature of the **RSASSA-PSS** type.

Starting from this principle, here's the implementation I now use.

```golang
type Signer struct {
    priKey p11.PrivateKey
    pubKey *rsa.PublicKey
}

var sigAlg = map[crypto.Hash]uint{
    crypto.SHA256: pkcs11.CKM_SHA256_RSA_PKCS_PSS,
    crypto.SHA384: pkcs11.CKM_SHA384_RSA_PKCS_PSS,
    crypto.SHA512: pkcs11.CKM_SHA512_RSA_PKCS_PSS,
}

var mgf = map[crypto.Hash]uint{
    crypto.SHA256: pkcs11.CKG_MGF1_SHA256,
    crypto.SHA384: pkcs11.CKG_MGF1_SHA384,
    crypto.SHA512: pkcs11.CKG_MGF1_SHA512,
}

func (s Signer) Public() crypto.PublicKey {
    return s.pubKey
}

func (s Signer) Sign(_ io.Reader, digest []byte, opts crypto.SignerOpts) ([]byte, error) {
    return s.priKey.Sign(*pkcs11.NewMechanism(pkcs11.CKM_RSA_PKCS_PSS, pkcs11.NewPSSParams(sigAlg[opts.HashFunc()], mgf[opts.HashFunc()], uint(opts.HashFunc().Size()))), digest)
}

func NewSigner(key p11.PrivateKey) (*Signer, error) {
    // Retrieve modulus n from the private key
    // Reminder: n = p * q
    modulus, err := p11.Object(key).Attribute(pkcs11.CKA_MODULUS)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var pubExp []byte
    // Retrieve public exponent (e: "always" 65537) from the private key
    // Reminder: φ(n) = (p - 1) * (q - 1), e such that 1 < e < φ(n) and e and φ(n) are co prime
    pubExp, err = p11.Object(key).Attribute(pkcs11.CKA_PUBLIC_EXPONENT)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Public key is (e, n)
    pubKey := &rsa.PublicKey{
        N: new(big.Int).SetBytes(modulus),
        E: int(new(big.Int).SetBytes(pubExp).Uint64()),
    }

    return &Signer{priKey: key, pubKey: pubKey}, nil
}
```

Prefixes are therefore no longer necessary, however, the correspondence between the hash algorithm identifier and the signature algorithm to be used, as well as the MGF to be used, is necessary.

Finally, in Go, the [signature algorithm](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/x509#SignatureAlgorithm) to be used is no longer **x509.SHA256WithRSA**, **x509.SHA384WithRSA** or **x509.SHA512WithRSA**, but rather **SHA256WithRSAPSS**, **SHA384WithRSAPSS** and **SHA512WithRSAPSS**.

Happy signing.